# Trying to copy files to Pods with `kubectl cp`, But getting Error: unknown flag: --all-namespaces

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

Trying to copy and execute a bash script in a POD (which has one container)

kubectl cp ../docker/scripts/upload_javadumps.sh  ${POD}:/opt -n apm

This commands works perfectly, But we have multiple Namespaces, Hence I wanted to use --all-namespaces like shown below 
 which errors out saying, Error: unknown flag: --all-namespaces

How Do I use --all-namspaces in kubectl cp command?

````
kubectl cp ../docker/scripts/upload_javadumps.sh  ${POD}:/opt --all-namespaces
echo "Successfully copied the upload_javadumps.sh script"```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `kubectl cp` flag `--all-namespaces` doesn't exist, you can check it with `kubectl cp -h`.

In your case I would go with simple bash loop like this:

```
for ns in namespace1 namespace2; do kubectl cp ../docker/scripts/upload_javadumps.sh ${POD}:/opt -n $ns;done
```

Comment: Hi, if it works for your - please accept the answer.